# Le sens de l'ouïe et de la vue ou le sens de l'ouïe et le sens de la vue

Tags: grammaire

Est-ce que cette construction grammaticale est correcte ?

> le sens de l'ouïe et de la vue qui sont visés

Answer (score 4):

L'expression

> le sens de l'ouïe et de la vue qui sont visés

n'est pas correcte, car deux sens ici sont concernés et non un seul. En revanche,

> les sens de l'ouïe et de la vue qui sont visés

pourrait être une partie d'une phrase qui soit correcte, mais il est bizarre de l'isoler ainsi, il manque un contexte. Toutefois, par exemple, on peut écrire :

> Ce sont les sens de l'ouïe et de la vue qui sont visés.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse 